# Force SourceTree ignore line endings in git files

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, line-endings

There are so many posts but still the resolution is not clear or isn't working for me. Problem seems to be well known..

1. I checked out my project in unix and git status shows no differences.
   Settings here:

   ```
   bash-3.2$ git config core.autocrlf
   false
   bash-3.2$ git config core.whitespace
   cr-at-eol
   ```
2. But I also like to use SourceTree (pointing to the same Unix code base through NFS mount) for some conveniences.
   Settings for those above attributes are exactly same.
   But SourceTree shows a bunch of differences in based on purely line endings.

> What is the straightforward solution for this?
>    How come SourceTree has no settings in the UI around this?

Comment: Open your files with a HEX-editor and look at what are the real endline chars. On Windows you should have CRLFs (no matter what numbers, it's 2 chars). Your code on Unix machine, pulled from git, may have LFs. That makes a difference. Git is "trained" to see that code as equal, SourceTree is not.

Comment: Even if I run "git status" from the shell provided by SourceTree it shows those differences. Thing is how to force SourceTree to ignore those differences?

Comment: I've got no idea how to configure SourceTree and if it is possible at all. But if you exchange code between developers with Git, you can setup Git to handle endlines.

Comment: Just made a couple of suggestions on a similar question, hope that helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30603750/git-picking-up-whitespace-changes-it-shouldnt?noredirect=1#comment49278669_30603750

Comment: I have 2 machines with the exact same version of `git` and `sourcetreeapp` installed. One machine's source tree ignore the line ending difference. The other machine show entire file is changed because of the line ending difference. I don't know what causes it...

Answer (score 17):

There is a `gear icon` near the diff-ui section of the SourceTree app that show your file difference, you can click on it and set it to `show whitespace` or `ignore whitespace`!! I googled for hours, and finally got the answer after searching for SourceTree equivalent of the git command:

```
Git version <= 1.8.3.4:
git diff --ignore-space-at-eol -b -w [commit] ...

Git version >= 1.8.4:
git diff --ignore-space-at-eol -b -w --ignore-blank-lines [commit] ...

See the options definition below:

--ignore-space-at-eol 
Ignore changes in whitespace at EOL.

-b 
--ignore-space-change 
Ignore changes in amount of whitespace. This ignores whitespace at line end, 
and considers all other sequences of one or more whitespace characters to be 
equivalent.

-w 
--ignore-all-space 
Ignore whitespace when comparing lines. This ignores differences even if one 
line has whitespace where the other line has none.

[git version 1.8.4+]--ignore-blank-lines 
Ignore changes whose lines are all blank.
```

[image: The screen shot]

References:

[The git command equivalent](https://coderwall.com/p/crj69a/from-a-useless-git-diff-to-a-useful-one)

[Source Tree app settings](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-1025)