# GIT picking up whitespace changes it shouldn't

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

After running our build process, some files are showing up in SourceTree with whitespace-only changes.  Leaving aside discussions about whether auto-generated files should be included in source control, my problem is this:

Files show up in the uncommitted window.  If I attempt to commit them, I get the error below.

Ideally I'd like to have SourceTree be smart enough to not display these files as modified in the first place.  Is there a good way to accomplish this?

> git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false commit -q -F C:----\fc1hkokv.mod -- ----.js
>
> On branch feature/14006-clinical-notes
>    Changes not staged for commit:
>      (use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
>      (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)
>
> modified:   xxxx.js
>   no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
>
> warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in xxx.js.
>   The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

Comment: Looks like those are newline characters changed. `LF will be replaced by CRLF in xxx.js`. Files are generated in Unix-mode, with LFs. Then they are commited with substitution to CRLF, and probably pulled to another user with different settings for newline chars.

Comment: Thanks @Nick - is there a way to tell SourceTree to ignore changes limited to just this?

Comment: That's not about SourceTree. Just setup the core.autocrlf the right way on all machines. http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Comment: What I mean is that if you set the right configuration, you won't need to tinker with SourceTree. Git is capable of handling endlines between different operation systems. OS X and Linux use `LF`, Windows uses `CRLF`, Git can store in any mode. But you need to have unified mode for all developers. Right now it looks like one pushes LFs and some other pushes CRLFs.

Comment: @Nick - I added `autocrlf=true` into .git/core under `[core]` but still these same files show up with the same meaningless end of file change, that I can't commit and have to just discard.  Did I miss something from your comments?

Comment: There's also `core.whitespace` if that is indeed about whitespace. http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Comment: @Nick - Windows 8.1.  The files are generated by a Node process, which I suspect explains the cr/lf difference.  I'll have a look at that link, thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79457/discussion-between-nick-volynkin-and-adam-rackis).

Comment: This situation is thoroughly discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf).