# How to ignore whitespace / CRLF changes in the beginning of a file in SourceTree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-diff

In the git comparison, I would like to ignore if there's a CRLF in the beginning of the files.

Like in this image, I want git to ignore the difference of the lines added:

[image]

Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force SourceTree ignore line endings in git files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30603417/force-sourcetree-ignore-line-endings-in-git-files)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make git diff --ignore-space-change the default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310033/how-to-make-git-diff-ignore-space-change-the-default)